# get ID and show details

Tags: java, file

i want to det ID number and display details.
mt .txt file is here:

when i use scanner class for get id number,and consol window for display detalis, all things is good and perfect.
but when i use a jtextfield for get id and a jlable for display detail information, program find just last record in file and not find other records.

my code is here:

```
    int idS=Integer.parsInt(JTextfield1.getText());
    File f=new File("C:\\SearchFile.txt");
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s;

    while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
        String[] st=s.split(" ");
        String id=st[0];
        String name=st[1];
        String mark=st[2];

        if(id.equals(String.valueOf(idS))){

            JLable1.setText(id+" "+name+ " "+mark);
        }
    }
```

please help!

Comment: could you provide a bit more code? Is it not a case that you set always the same label?

Comment: the jlabe or jtextfield numbers are not real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have some blanck spaces arround the String you read from File. Try equalIgnoreCase() by assuming that ID is not case sensitive.

```
   id.trim().equalIgnorecase(String.valueOf(idS));
```

Hope this will help.